# Event will not trigger

Tags: javascript, forms, onchange

I have a form that has multiple inputs. One input is where user can input an ID. I need to verify the ID is unique. I want to call a JavaScript function for a onchange event. However, I can't get it to trigger. I have a console.log but it never hits when I make a change in the input so I am doing something wrong.
This is the function I am trying to call on the on change

```js
function checkUniqueID() {
  console.log("here");
  var $counter = 0;
  var tag = document.forms["userform"]["new_id"].value;
  while ($counter < $totalItems) {

  }
};
```

```html
<div class="six wide field">
  <label for="ID">ID</label>
  <input type="text" id="new" name="new_id" placeholder="ID" onchange="checkUniqueID()">
</div>
```

I can't even get the console.log ("here") to trigger

Comment: @lintu — Why would that make a difference for **this** code? The JS doesn't try to touch the DOM until the function is called.

Comment: The live demo successfully logs "here" (it then errors on something else) but I can't reproduce the problem with the code you've provided.

Comment: Your input element is not inside a form, so your selector won't work as-is. `let tag = document.getElementById("new").value` would work...

Comment: `onchange` triggers after you loose focus.

Answer (score 1):

The `onchange` HTML attribute triggers when the input loses focus.
So, if you correctly have your `input#new_id` inside a form like this:

```
<form name="userform">
  <div class="six wide field">
  <label for="ID">ID</label>
  <input type="text" id="new" name="new" placeholder="ID">
 </div>
</form>
```

Adding an eventListener in your script file would be enough.

```
document.userform.new_id.onchange=function(){
    alert("ID changed to: "+this.value);
};
```

With jQuery would be as easy as:

```
$("#new").change(function(){
    alert("ID changed to: "+$(this).value;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/edbL3kgp/

Comment: k3lly.dev. thank you for your input.  Some reason one I use your exact java script example from the jsfiddle.net example, I still can't get it to trigger on my ID change.  do I need to put that JS somewhere specific in my code.  I am working in a .php file.  This .php file has HTML and other javascript in it that is working